# Writing multithreaded TCP server on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

At work I have been tasked with implementing a TCP server as part of a Modbus slave device. I have done a lot of reading both here on stack exchange and on the internet in general (including the excellent http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) but I am struggling with a design issue. In summary, my device can accept just 2 connections and on each connection will be incoming modbus requests which I must process in my main controller loop and then reply with success or failure status. I have the following ideas of how to implement this.

1. Have a listener thread that creates, binds, listens and accepts connections, then spawns a new pthread to listen on the connection for incoming data and close connection after an idle timeout period. If the number of active threads is currently 2, new connections are instantly closed to ensure only 2 are allowed.
2. Do not spawn new threads from the listener thread, instead use select() to detect incoming connection requests as well as incoming modbus connects on active connections (similar to the approach in Beejs guide).
3. Create 2 listener threads each of which creates a socket (same IP and port number) which can block on accept() calls, then close the socket fd and deal with the connection. Here I am (perhaps naively) assuming that this will only allow max of 2 connections which I can deal with using blocking reads.

I have been using C++ for a long time but I am fairly new to Linux development. I would really welcome any suggestions as to which of the above approaches is best (if any) and if my inexperience with Linux means that any of them are really really bad ideas. I am keen to avoid fork() and stick to pthreads as incoming modbus requests are going to be queued and read off a main controller loop periodically. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third alternative won't work, you can only bind to the local address once.

I would probably use your second alternative, unless you need to do a lot of processing in which case a combination of the first to alternatives might be useful.

The combination of the two first alternative I'm thinking of is to have the main thread (the one you always have when a program starts) create two worker threads, then go a blocking `accept` call to wait for a new connection. When a new connection arrives, tell one of the threads to start working on the new connection and go back to block on `accept`. When the second connection is accepted you tell the other thread to work on that connection. If both connections are open already, either don't accept until one connection is closed, or wait for new connections but close them immediately.

Comment: I like the sound of this - the only problem is that my main loop strictly must not block. It must do processing and periodically deal with requests from the listener threads. With this in mind you say option 2. would be best?

Comment: @mathematician1975 You can still use my method, but instead of blocking on `accept` use short or no-timeout `select` (or make the listening socket non-blocking and use `accept` and check for `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`) to know when a connection can be accepted.

Comment: I think given my time constraints this is the best solution for me to pursue in the short term. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only dealing with 2 connections, thread per connection is perfect for this kind of application. Object oriented approaches using non-blocking or asynchronous I/O would be better if you needed to scale up to thousands of connections. 2 listener threads makes sense, you don't need to close the accept fd. Just come back to accept on it when the connection is completed. In fact, a variation is to have three threads blocked doing accept. If two of the threads are actively handling connections, then the third resets the newly created connection (or returns busy response, whatever is appropriate for your device).

To have all three threads block on accept, you need to have the main thread create and bind your socket before the three threads launch to do their accept/handle processing.

The [man page for pthreads on Linux](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) indicates that accept is thread-safe. (The section under thread-safe functions lists the functions that are not thread-safe, go figure.)

Comment: You mean option 3 in my question?

Comment: @mathematician1975: yes, I was thinking a variation of option 3, but with three threads accepting.

Comment: But the other answer here says I can only bind once, which rules out option 3. ??

Comment: @mathematician1975: bind and listen once in the main thread, then launch threads to do accept. Linux supports this mode, on other OS's you might have to protect the accept call with a mutex.

Comment: Ah i see - so pass the socket fd to the other threads? So before ANY connection, I would have 2 threads simultaneously blocking on accept() ? And this is thread safe?

Comment: @mathematician1975: It has been in my experience on Linux, but worst case is to guard the accept call with a mutex, since I can't find any documentation saying it is supposed to be thread-safe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12429/discussion-between-user315052-and-mathematician1975)

Answer (score 2):

All of the design option you propose are not very object oriented, and they're all geared more towards C than C++.  If your work allows you to use boost, then the Boost.Asio library is fantastic for making simple (and complex) socket servers.  You could take nearly any of their examples and trivially extend it to only allow 2 active connections, closing all others as soon as they are opened.

Off the top of my head, their simple HTTP server could be modified to do this by keeping a static counter in the connection class (inc in the constructor, dec in the destructor), and when a new one is created check the count and decide whether to close the connection.  The connection class could also gain a boost::asio::deadline_timer to keep track of timeouts.

This would most closely resemble your first design choice, boost could do this in 1 thread and in the background does something similar to `select()` (usually `epoll()`).  But this is the "C++ way", and in my opinion using `select()` and raw `pthread`s is the C way.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I totally agree with you regarding the C++ and OO aspects of it. However, given current constraints on my time I think I will have to pursue the raw linux API approach as it has taken me time to get used to it and need to get a prototype out fast. However, once the project gets accepted I think I will definitely favour this approach