# C - How to limit the number of inbound connections in a server when using select()

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm still new to C socket programming but I was able to create some simple client and server programs.
I'm programming a server that listens for TCP connections, its duty is answering to clients' requests and then close the communication when the client sends a special sequence of bytes (or when it disconnects, of course).

I started coding the server using the `accept()` function inside an endless loop: the server waits for a client, accept()'s it, does all the stuff, close()'s the socket descriptor at the end and goes back again waiting to accept a new client.

Since I want to serve one client at a time I called the listen function in this way: `listen(mysocket, 1);`

Everything worked pretty well, but then a new problem came out. The server part explained above runs in a separated thread (let's call it thread #2) and the main thread (thread #1) must be able to tell it to terminate. I created a global variable then, if this variable is set to 1 (by thread #1) thread #2 must terminate. The problem is that thread #2 gets stuck when the `accept()` function is called, thus it can't periodically check the global variable.

I clearly needed a timeout value for that function: "if there isn't a connection to accept, check the value of the global variable, continue waiting for new connection if set to 0 or terminate if set to 1".

I googled for a solution then and found that the `select()` function does the thing that I need. It's a little bit different though, I discovered for the first time the `fd_set` and all the FD_* macros. I modified the server part to make it work with the `select()` function and everything works really nice, but here comes the last problem, the one that I'm not able to solve.
If call the listen function this way: `listen(socket, 1);` but the server still accepts and serves multiple connections at the same time. Does this depend because `select()` works with fd_set's? I'm using some examples I found on the web and, when a connection is accepted, it creates a new socket descriptor that goes in the set with all the others.
I'd like to accept the connection of just one client, I wrote a simple code that recognizes if the connecting client should be served or not, but is there a way to disconnect it server side? I know that I have to use the `close()` function to close a socket descriptor, but when using `select()` I'm working with fd_set's and I don't really know what to do to close them.
Or, is there a way to limit the number of socket descriptors in a set? I found the FD_SETSIZE macro, but I wasn't able to make it work and I'm not even sure if it fixes the problem.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I asked a similar question a few weeks ago - I wanted to be able to allow only 2 incoming connections. I got some good answers, so it might be of some use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993586/writing-multithreaded-tcp-server-on-linux

Comment: "I'm working with fd_set's and I don't really know what to do to close them" Close *what*? you can close the fds. You cannot close the fd_set as a whole. (well: only in a loop)

Comment: Thanks mathematician1975! It wasn't easy finding examples that fits my needs, I probably used wrong search keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listen()` function has a `backlog` argument that determines how many incoming request may be pending before they *may* be turned away. This is worded carefully so that the OS implementation can support *more* than what you specify in the `listen()` call. You may not be able to control the exact number of backlogged connections.

If you must support only one client at a time, then accept a second connection but tell the new client that the connection is not available at this time, and then close the new connection. This also has the benefit that you have the opportunity to tell the client why the connection is not available.

Comment: Ok! I'm telling the new client the connection is not available already, but how do I close the connection? I have the `fd_set read_fds` with the new connection, I should "extract" the socket descriptor from that and do a `close()`?

Comment: Yes, that would do it. You probably already have the handle in a variable somewhere other than in `read_fds`, since there really isn't an easy way to "extract" a handle value from an `fd_set`.

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right! I was thinking at how getting the handle from the `read_fds` to close it but couldn't find a way. As you say, I have it in a variable other than in `read_fds`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the listen() socket in the fd_set, too. (I don't understand from your question if you already do this) If the select indicates that listen socket is readable, you can call accept on the listen socket. accept returns exactly one fd. You can put the returned fd into the fd_set, too. Threads are more or less orthogonal to this. (systemcalls are atomic), but you can of course screw things up.

The backlog parameter for listen is more or less unrelated; it just specifies how many *embryonic* sockets the system should maintain simultaneously (the connection buildup uses resources, even before the socket becomes usable, as indicated by listen returning the fresh fd) Once the three-way handshake is completed accept will return the fd, and the *embryonic* connections are born as the new socket fd.

The getdtablesize() macro is a remainder from old times. In modern implementations it is based on getrlimit().

The underlying problem with FD_SETSIZE is that fd_set must be a lvalue, such that it can be assigned. So it must be fixed size. (it is probably an array inside a struct) To avoid fixed sized structures you could use poll() instead of select() (or use multiple smaller fd_sets ;-)

Comment: Your explanation of backlog isn't correct. Connections on the backlog queue are already fully formed and ready to accept: they just haven't been accepted yet because the application hasn't done so. There are other queues for 'embryonic' connections still in the handshake phase.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using the windows API , you could try Critical Sections.